# Migrate database oracle to postgresql : procedure

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

we are going to migrate our database from Oracle to PostgreSQL.

I am new in PostgreSQL. We have a procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USPX_TEST (NAME IN VARCHAR2,cb_results_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
BEGIN
 OPEN cb_results_cursor FOR
          SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMP_NAME = NAME;
END USPX_TEST;
```

Please provide me how to convert this same procedure in postgreSQL.

NOTE: we need to return the result in a cursor using out parameter

Thanks in advance...

Comment: there is no concept of SP's, you use a function. Example in the ref below:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-create-procedure/

Answer (score 0):

To return a result in Postgres, you use a function, not a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function USPX_TEST (NAME IN VARCHAR2)
  returns setof employees
as
$$
  SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMP_NAME = NAME;
$$
language sql;
```

The use it like a table:

```
select *
from USPX_TEST('Zaphod');
```